# Make one popup which can be used on multiple pages in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have two web-form pages in ASP, one for viewing a record and and another for editing it. I would like to have a link on each which popups a box to allow editing a certain property on the record. If I only placed it on the Edit page, I would use an UpdatePanel but I would have to copy and paste code if I wanted it on the View page as well. Is there a way to have the code in one area which be can be referenced and used from both pages?

*Edit*: I know I could make a custom control to handle it although it would include all its HTML on the page when the page first loads, not when the link is clicked.

*Edit2*: I wanted to avoid having the contents of the popup rendered when the page first loads  but now I realize it's just a matter of not binding any data in it until the Postback occurs.

Comment: Have you thought about making the UpdatePanel a ServerControl and than referencing that control in both pages.

Comment: You could always load the custom control dynamically....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the bulk of the panel a user control (ascx). Then just put a thin wrapper around it on both the pages where you need it. The bulk of the code is then in the ascx and ascx.vb and does not need to be written twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a MasterPage for both the pages, and put the popup with UpdatePanel on the master page, so you can access it from both the pages.

Hope it helps.
Don't forget to upvote it if it solves you problem.
Thanks.. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting way of doing it. I picked Jay's answer though because it could be more flexible with a user control, e.g., it could more easily be added to third page.